# Tkinter when a button is clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So im making a game in Tkinter but what I want to do is when I click a button on my keyboard for example "w" it runs a function that increments x by 5 for example.

Heres my code.

```
__author__ = 'Zac'
from Tkinter import *
from random import randint

class Application:
    def circle(self, r, x, y):
        return (x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r)

    def square(self, s, x, y):
        return (x, y, s, s)

    def __init__(self, canvas, r, x, y):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.r = r
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.ball = canvas.create_oval(self.circle(r, x, y))


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 1000, height = 1000)
canvas.pack()

ball1 = Application(canvas, 20, 50, 50)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `widget.bind` method to bind keypress with event handler.

For example:

```
....

ball1 = Application(canvas, 20, 50, 50)

def increase_circle(event):
    canvas.delete(ball1.ball)
    ball1.r += 5
    ball1.ball = canvas.create_oval(ball1.circle(ball1.r, ball1.x, ball1.y))

root.bind('<w>', increase_circle)  # <--- Bind w-key-press with increase_circle

root.mainloop()
```

See [**Events and Bindings**](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

Comment: Thanks it worked just one question why do you event?

Comment: @Zac, I added a link. Reading it will answer your question. :)